# Plotly Sankey: How to use defined node positions with vertical orientation? (without cutting off parts of the chart?)

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python, sankey-diagram

I am encountering frustrating layout or plot dimension issues when creating a **vertical** flow chart with Plotly's Sankey figure. Parts of the chart get **cut-off** like so:

[image: Cut-off Sankey diagram]

The **core of the problem** appears to be the use of *defined node positions* in conjunction with `orientation = "v"`. When changing the `domain` x and y parameters of the figure to [0.5,1], the entire charts gets visible, but the layout is terrible, and surely so is the fix. My question is:

### How can you draw a vertical Sankey chart with defined node positions?

The problem is easily reproduced by changing the Sankey example given on [Plotly's website](https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/#define-node-position):

**Horizontal Sankey chart with defined node positions**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(go.Sankey(
    arrangement = "snap",
    node = {
        "label": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
        "x": [0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5],
        "y": [0.7, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3],
        'pad':10},  # 10 Pixels
    link = {
        "source": [0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 5],
        "target": [5, 3, 4, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3],
        "value": [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]}))

fig.show()
```

[image: Horizontally aligned Sankey chart]

This produces the example. When changing the `orientation` parameter (default is "h") of Sankey's figure reference, the charts gets cut-off.

**Vertical Sankey chart with defined node positions**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Sankey(
    orientation = "v",
    arrangement = "snap",
    node = {
        "label": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
        "x": [0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5],
        "y": [0.7, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3],
        'pad':10},  # 10 Pixels
    link = {
        "source": [0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 5],
        "target": [5, 3, 4, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3],
        "value": [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]}))

fig.show()
```

[image: Cut-off Sankey diagram]

When removing the x and y parameters of the figure's node configuration, the chart no longer gets cut-off, but the order is lost.

**Vertical Sankey chart without defined node positions**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Sankey(
    orientation = "v",
    arrangement = "snap",
    node = {
        "label": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
#         "x": [0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5],
#         "y": [0.7, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3],
        'pad':10},  # 10 Pixels
    link = {
        "source": [0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 5],
        "target": [5, 3, 4, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3],
        "value": [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]}))

fig.show()
```

[image: Well-drawn vertical Sankey chart]

Lastly, by changing the figure's domain values for x and y, the entire chart is visible, but I doubt that this will hold for more data and be useful building a Dash app.

**Quick fix**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Sankey(
    domain = dict(
        x =  [0.5,1],
        y =  [0.5,1]
    ),
    orientation = "v",
    arrangement = "snap",
    node = {
        "label": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
        "x": [0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5],
        "y": [0.7, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3],
        'pad':10},  # 10 Pixels
    link = {
        "source": [0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 5],
        "target": [5, 3, 4, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3],
        "value": [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]}))

fig.show()
```

[image]